# How to change uwidget alignment on/after construction?

Tags: c++, unreal-4, unreal

Have no idea how to align/realign uwidgets via c++.
I have a following widget structure: UButton->UOverlay->UImage.
Have to make UOverlay to HFill and VFill the UButton

Comment: I think there are two ways to do this. In straight c++ code like you are doing or using Slate with macros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution. Add child returns a panel slot, which we can then cast to a button slot and use it to set alignment.

Edit: This solution crashes the engine. Still can't figure out why

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SizeBox` element as holder of your widget [image].

Then you can add your widget as a child, cast returned slot to `SizeBoxSlot` and then use `SetAlignment` functions.
[image]
It works for me.